# Different dimens for different screen sizes

Tags: android, xml

I have different dimens for different densities, but there is a problem with xxxhdpi

There are two phones:

1. Pixel 7 pro

- size: large
- size: 6,71"
- density: 560dpi (xxxhdpi)
- resolution: 1440x3120 (412x892 in dp)
- ratio: long

2. Pixel XL

- size: large
- size: 5,5"
- density: 560dpi (xxxhdpi)
- resolution: 1440x2560 (412x732 in dp)
- ratio: long

i tried to create

- values-h732dp-xxxhdpi for XL
- values-h892dp-xxxhdpi for 7pro

or

- values-sw360dp-xxxhdpi for XL
- values-sw384dp-xxxhdpi for 7pro

but, it doesn't make sense
Instead, they take the dimen value from the values-sw384dp-xxhdpi in the first case or values-sw384dp-xxxhdpi in the second case

on what aspect should I set the name of the "values" folder?

[now i have this structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rozq.png)